# How can I write tests for my Windows (phone) 8.1 app if I am not using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 app that is not created using the MVVM pattern. Is there a way to create tests for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio to produce **Coded UI Tests**.

It allows to record test as being a end user.

Then the generated code allows to handle UI objects and assert they are visible,  red, good size ,...

Handling UI objects also allows to change the conditions of the test.

But you need a VS 2015 Entreprise Edition or a VS 2013 Ultimate (may be Premium also)

You can also test your data access layer classes /business logic if you separate them of User interface with standard UI tests.

Creating separate libraries for putting Business Logic, Data Access Layer can help to write tests

Regards